# Search Shopify products by keyword with JSON response

Tags: java, php, json, shopify, android-json

I am building an application for a shopify store and have a requirement of displaying products using a keyword that the user enters.

I searched over and found this url working:

**...e.myshopify.com/search?q=short&type=product&view=json**

where I append the keyword to the **?q** variable.
But i need a JSON response for my application. It does not gives a Json response even after mentioning the **view=json** field.

Pleas help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to write a simple template in your theme to render the JSON you need in response to that JSON view. Just create the file `templates/search.json.liquid`, which can be as simple as the following:

```
{% layout none %}
{{ search.results | json }}
```